# Create compact string in R with repitions

Tags: r

How do I create a compact string in R that consists of repetitions? I know this is a basic question but I did not find any relevant answer to it.

Here an example: I want to create a string that consists of 10x repeating "p":

```
a1 <- c("ppppppppppp")
a1
```

[1] "pppppppppp"

but NOT this:

```
a2 <- rep("p", 10)
a2
```

[1] "p" "p" "p" "p" "p" "p" "p" "p" "p" "p"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
paste(rep("p", 10), collapse="")
# [1] "pppppppppp"
```